# Computing Percentages of each Subgroup

Tags: r, dplyr

This question has been answered before, but solutions not working for my particular situation.

```
col1   |   col2
 A     |    0
 B     |    1
 A     |    0
 A     |    1
 B     |    0
```

I'm basically looking for this:

```
col1   |   col2   |   Percentage
 A     |    0     |      0.67
 A     |    1     |      0.33
 B     |    0     |      0.50
 B     |    1     |      0.50
```

Both columns are factors. The following solutions is what I keep finding on other threads:

```
df %>% group_by(col1, col2) %>% summarise(n=n()) %>% mutate(freq = n / sum(n))
or something along those lines.
```

In fact, group_by doesn't really seem to be doing anything at all. It's not giving me an 'n' or 'freq' column. Don't know what I'm doing wrong. Is it because I'm working with factors? Also, if it's not obvious, the values provided in the columns are hypothetical.

Comment: I don't understand this question.  Your code is giving exactly the same output as expected

Comment: Get the following error: Error: n() should only be called in a data context
Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace

Comment: Can you check your `dplyr` version.  I used `packageVersion('dplyr')#
[1] ‘0.8.1’` on `R 3.6.0`

Comment: Checked versions for both, they match up.

Comment: Can you try on a fresh session as I can't reproduce your issue

Comment: Wow. What do you know, it worked. That's odd, any idea what could cause that to happen?

Comment: If you have loaded tidyverse and other packges, there is a chance that some of the functions in one package may be present in other packge with a different behavior.  This could mask the existing function and you get a different behavior because the function is from a different package.

Comment: Okay, I'll keep that in mind. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option would be to get the frequency count after grouping by 'col1', then with the 'col2' also as grouping column, divide that frequency by the already created frequency

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(col1) %>%
   mutate(n = n()) %>%
   group_by(col2, add = TRUE) %>% 
   summarise(freq = n()/n[1])
# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   col1 [2]
#  col1   col2  freq
#  <chr> <int> <dbl>
#1 A         0 0.667
#2 A         1 0.333
#3 B         0 0.5  
#4 B         1 0.5
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(col1 = c("A", "B", "A", "A", "B"), col2 = c(0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L
))
```

Comment: Like I said, group_by doesn't seem to be doing anything for some reason so it breaks after 2nd pipe operation because there's no 'n'.

Comment: @user10939484  I showed the data in my post, along with the expected (which matches with your expected)

Comment: @user10939484  Have you by chance loaded `plyr` library along with `dplyr`.  In that case, it could mask the `summarise/mutate`.  So you may need to explicitly add `%>% dplyr::mutate(n = n()) %>% ... %>% dplyr::summarise(freq = n()/n[1])`

Comment: plyr is loaded as well because I have ggplot loaded. I tried your suggestion with no luck. So I used your data, and the same thing happens. It's not grouping and outputting a count. Any ideas?

Comment: @user10939484  Can you try on a fresh session with only `dplyr` loaded as I can't reproduce the behavior.  Even your code is giving the correct output